# Splitting list of elements without numpy array function

Tags: python

Example: I have a list:

```
[8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2]
```

And I need to make it look like this but without using numpy.array_split():

```
[[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
```

How can I do it? Not only for this one case, but when I have 4 elements, I want to have 2 and 2, (9 - 3,3,3 and 16 - 4,4,4,4) etc.

Comment: What do you want to return when the original list has 5 elements?

Comment: Maybe this answer is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: Do you want to only split lists of length n, where n is a square number?

Comment: @qwerty22 SO is not a homework site. Show what you have tried before asking for help in either direction. Votes to Close for lack of effort. End of Review.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the square root of the list's length then split it using a list comprehension. This will work for lists with the length of 4, 9, 16, ...:

```
lst = [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2]
lst2 = [8, 3, 4, 1]

def split_equal(lst):
    len_ = len(lst)

    # returns emtpy list, if the list has no item.
    if len_ == 0:
        return []
    
    n = int(len_ ** 0.5)
    return [lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len_, n)]
```

output:

```
[[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
[[8, 3], [4, 1]]
```

Comment: I think we posted the exact same code haha, only the loop is different

Comment: Note that the function throws an error if the length of the list is 0, as `range()` argument 3 cannot be 0.

Comment: @Haukland thanks for mentioning. updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that:

```
def splitter(inlist):
    n = len(inlist)
    m = int(n ** 0.5)
    if m*m != n:
        raise Exception("")
    return [[inlist[i+j] for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]

print(splitter([8, 3, 4, 1]))
print(splitter([8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2]))
print(splitter([8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2, 8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6]))
```

Result:

```
[[8, 3], [3, 4]]
[[8, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 5]]
[[8, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 5], [4, 1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 9, 6]]
```

Carefull, it will crash if the square of the len of input list is not integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def equal_array_split(arr, split_arr_len):
    array_length = len(arr)
    if array_length % split_arr_len == 0:
        return [arr[i:i+split_arr_len] for i in range(0,array_length,split_arr_len)]
    else:
        return "Invalid split array length!!"


print(equal_array_split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3))
print(equal_array_split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],4))
print(equal_array_split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],8))
print(equal_array_split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],2))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the list with a list comprehension. Assuming the input is a square number length:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2]
n = int(np.sqrt(len(arr)))
result = [arr[i*n:(i+1)*n] for i in range(int(n))]
```

Comment: Not quite: OP - "without using numpy.array_split()". Replace the sqrt if desired.

Answer (score 0):

the split value being a square

```
list = [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2]
result = []
N = split_value #split_value being the value required to split the list
for i in range(0,len(list),N):
    result.append(list[i:i+N])
    
print(result)
```

Comment: As N is a constant, this will split any list into lists of three elements

Comment: We can vary N as per requirement. Also assuming that the split results into a square matrix only

Answer (score 0):

Whitout numpy....

```
a = [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2]

splitedSize = 3
a_splited = [a[x:x+splitedSize] for x in range(0, len(a), splitedSize)]

print(a_splited)
```